# React-firebase-capacitor: Firebase Sign In not working on IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, capacitor

I have a react web app using firebase. I want to wrap it for mobile with capacitor. I can get it into android studio and run it perfectly fine, however, in the IOS simulators, it will not sign in.

I can create an account, which means I can communicate with firebase, but not sign into one. I have used safari to look at the fetch request (which is shown), but it does not give an error or reason why no response is returned. Is there a dependency or something in Xcode settings that I need to change for IOS to let me sign in to firebase?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.